# android : Top View of the Dialog Activity not displayed

Tags: android, dialog, android-activity, android-framelayout

I have weird problem of the android.

I need to play video in dialog activity with Image "Close".

My Dialog View :

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/video_frame"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@android:color/white">
 <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/close"

                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:src="@drawable/delete3"             />
    <VideoView 
            android:id="@+id/video_view"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

in the Manifest:

```
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"  
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:name="ua.adertise.banners.VideoDialog2" />
```

But in the horizontal position of the telephone I've got:

[image]

and in the vertical position :

[image]

I experiemented with wrap_content, match_parent, margins, FrameLayout, but always got the same result. What can be solution to this ?

Comment: This shouldn't be your problem but, `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`, doesn't do anything for a `View` whose parent is a `LinearLayout` only `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: no, unfortunately. problem is not in this case.